# Installing hibernate bundle in AEM OSGI

Tags: java, hibernate, osgi, aem

**I got hibernate jar as osgi bundle from** -http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-osgi.

**When I installed it in fresh AEM 6.1 , I got the following error -**

```
Unresolved constraint in bundle org.hibernate.osgi [448]: Unable to resolve 448.0: missing requirement [448.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.persistence)(version>=2.1.0)))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.hibernate.osgi [448]: Unable to resolve 448.0: missing requirement [448.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.persistence)(version>=2.1.0))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4095)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2114)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:977)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:964)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.InstallHelper.doRun(InstallHelper.java:67)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BaseUpdateInstallHelper.doRun(BaseUpdateInstallHelper.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BaseUpdateInstallHelper.run(BaseUpdateInstallHelper.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
04.01.2016 21:43:00.498 *ERROR* [FelixDispatchQueue] org.hibernate.osgi FrameworkEvent ERROR (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.hibernate.osgi [448]: Unable to resolve 448.0: missing requirement [448.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.persistence)(version>=2.1.0))).
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the persistent API 2.1 is missing. Which means there have to be another bundle which exports the javax.persistence package with version 2.1.